# How to get the immediate parent name for a sampler in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

How to get the immediate parent name for a sampler in Jmeter. I have many transaction controllers. I am using Jmeter 5.3
I have a beanshell script for the same which is as below, but it always prints the very first controller name.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Collection;

StandardJMeterEngine engine = ctx.getEngine();
Field test = engine.getClass().getDeclaredField("test");
test.setAccessible(true);
HashTree testPlanTree = (HashTree) test.get(engine);

SearchByClass simpleCtrlSearch= new SearchByClass(GenericController.class);
testPlanTree.traverse(simpleCtrlSearch);
Collection simpleControllers = simpleCtrlSearch.getSearchResults();

for (Object simpleController : simpleControllers) {
    log.info(((GenericController) simpleController).getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general this is either not possible or not too simple.

For particular your case if you need to determine the name of the [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) for the particular Sampler you can go for [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) and the following code:

```
if (sampleEvent.isTransactionSampleEvent()) {
    log.info("Transaction Controller name: " + sampleEvent.result.getSampleLabel())
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks for your answer buddy, but I need to use a  substring of controller name as prefix for their samplers. And I doubt if this could do this 

Comment: Thanks for the explanation buddy, but I'm not telepathic enough to guess what is your use case. This answer answers your question in its original form. Using full or partial Transaction Controller's name as a part of Samplers name is also possible